# Upload multiple file through plumber API in R

Tags: r, api, file-upload, upload, plumber

I am Developing `REST API` using **Plumber in R**. In which I have a module where I was support to upload multiple CEL file and runs the algorithms, get the output and show it in the front-end.

I had refer this code but I am confused Is this code is correct or not.

**plumber_api.R**

```
    library(plumber)
    library(Rook)
    
    #* Upload file
    #* @param upload File to upload
    #* @post /uploadfile
    function(req, res){
      fileInfo <- list(formContents = Rook::Multipart$parse(req))
      ## The file is downloaded in a temporary folder
      tmpfile <- fileInfo$formContents$upload$tempfile
      ## Copy the file to a new folder, with its original name
      fn <- file.path('~/Downloads', fileInfo$formContents$upload$filename)
      file.copy(tmpfile, fn)
      ## Send a message with the location of the file
      res$body <- paste0("Your file is now stored in ", fn, "\n")
      res
    }
```

**start_plumber_api.R**

```
plumber::plumb("C:/wamp64/www/testing/upload.R")$run(port = 1234)
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:1234/uploadfile" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Upload CEL File</label><br>
    <input type="file" id="files" accept=".CEL, .gz" multiple />
    <input type="submit" value="upload">
  </form>
```

**Getting this Error**

```
Warning in Rook::Multipart$parse(req) : bad content body
```

Can anyone tell me Is this code is correct to upload CEL file or not and also Can anyone please explain me what does the error what does it indicates???????

Please HELP!

Thank You In Advance

Answer (score 3):

If anyone faces with the same issue like me.

You can refer this Github link:-

https://github.com/rstudio/plumber/issues/579

```
#* @param f:[file]
#* @post /upload
function(f) {
  names(f)
}
```

**This Function will enables you to upload multiple file at a time whether it may be any file and before uploading your files you have to restrict which file you want to upload as input.**