# R Plumber XLSX POST file

Tags: r, api, post, xlsx, plumber

I would like to receive an XLSX file in a Plumber endpoint. After seeing the following posts about it, the next code is what I ended up doing:

- [Upload csv file to REST API with R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25733679/7092954)
- [Upload multiple file through plumber API in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66219036/7092954)
- [How to download and/or extract data stored in a 'raw' binary zip object within a response object in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58494604/7092954)

sender:

```r
library(httr)

POST(paste0(Sys.getenv('SERVER_HOST'), '/', Sys.getenv('SERVER_ENDPOINT')),
    body = list(f = upload_file(file.path('test.xlsx'))))
```

server:

```r
library(readxl)
library(jsonlite)

#* @param /f:[file]
#* @post /data
function(f) {
  filename <- 'read.xlsx'
  conn <- file(filename, 'wb')
  content <- Reduce(function(acc, cur) paste0(acc, cur), f[1])
  decoded <- base64_dec(f[[1]])
  writeBin(decoded, con = conn)
  close(conn)
  print(read_excel(filename))
}
```

But the saved downloaded `read.xslx` file is different than `test.xlsx`. Can anyone, please, help me?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the server:

```r
library(readxl)
library(jsonlite)
library(readr)

#* @post /data
function(req, res) {
  filename <- 'read.xlsx'
  content <- req$body$f$value
  write_file(content, filename)
  print(read_excel(filename))
}
```

To work properly